# how to fetch records from multiple database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to fetch the records from 2 different databases using join or any other methods.
I have created different connection to connect with two databases but I don't know how I can execute the query and which connection should I used to fetch the records.
Any suggestions?

Comment: We need to know more about your data layer and what you try to get so far. We also need to know if is replicate data as master/slave strategy or different data.

Comment: You didn't really give us enough information to answer your question. Are the databases on the same server, or different servers? If they're on the same server, then you don't need two separate connections.

Comment: Database on the different server. And I have created separate connection for both like $con1 & $con2 where $con1 and $con2 are connections of two different servers.